# How do I put arrays which consist of variables that are attached to URL's into image placeholders? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, variables

```
var imagesID = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4", "Image5", "Image6"];

function setImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gardenList.length; i++) {
    image(imagesID[i]++, gardenList[i]++);
  }
}
```

gardenList consists of a list of variables that are chosen by the user and are added to the end of an array as the user checks boxes. What I'm having trouble with is that when the function loops for as long as the length of gardenList.Length, the program says that image() id parameter value (NaN) is not a string. "Image1" and so on are the IDs for image placeholders. The variables in gardenList consist of URLs and would look something like this:

var lettuce = "https://bhvifbvijcncjowcw"
gardenList = [lettuce, ...]  Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding unnecessary `++` in the loop. This should work

```js
var imagesID = ["Image1", "Image2", "Image3", "Image4", "Image5", "Image6"];

function setImage() {
  for (var i = 0; i < gardenList.length; i++) {
    image(imagesID[i], gardenList[i]);
  }
}
```